# Am I correct to assume one cannot forward-declare a library's opaque pointer type?

Tags: c, forward-declaration, opaque-pointers

There are a lot of questions out there about forward declarations and opaque types, but most seem to be from the perspective of the library author, or people trying to use incomplete types without pointers or some such.

I'm using a library whose interface accepts/returns `FOO *` pointers. I'd like to confirm that I cannot (or should not) somehow forward-declare `FOO` or `FOO *` in my header file (which defines a struct with a `FOO *` member).

I do know that I could just `#include <library.h>` in both my header and my .c file, but since this is really just a learning project, I wanted to get clarification. (On the one hand, it seems like a forward-declaration might be possible, since my struct member is only a pointer and thus its size is known without knowing what `FOO` is—but on the other hand, I don't know if it's valid/smart to `typedef` something to `FOO` when the library is already doing that.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How do you know what to forward declare it as? It could be `typedef int FOO;` or `typedef struct FOO FOO;` or others.

Comment: You already answered your question in the last paragraph. You should always `#include <library.h>`, and you should never typedef something to `FOO` when the library is already doing that.

Comment: Long time no C (pun intended), but if you `#include <library.h>` in your header, as you should if you're using a type that's declared in it, and you `#include "yourfile.h"` in your file.c, as you always should, you don't need to `#include <library.h>` in your file.c. I would always include every library I needed in my header and in my .c I'd only include my own header and stuff like stdio.h or math.h that I only need in my .c. But like I said in the beginning: Long time no C, so I might be wrong about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you never need to dereference the pointer, then you can use an opaque type pointer if you know the struct tag name for it:

```
typedef struct FOO FOO;
```

You can now create `FOO *` variables, and use them.  And you probably could find the structure tag from the header file, but you should be aware that the library owners could change it at any time.

It is still usually best to include the official header, but if most of your code is not accessing the actual library, just passing around a handle to something returned by the library, you can avoid the 'cost' of including the actual header.  You should measure what that cost is before deciding on what is probably premature optimization.  It might be argued that if you have to ask the question, you don't know enough to be sure of doing it right, and you're in danger of getting burnt.

Note that you cannot create actual variables of the type; for that to work, the compiler needs to know how big the structure actually is, which means you need the details from the header.

Strictly speaking, if you don't know the tag name, that won't work.  And likewise, if the structure doesn't have a tag, you can't do it either.  And if it isn't a structure type, you can't do it.

Note that if you know the structure tag, you can also write:

```
struct FOO *fp;
```

If you have to get inventive, everything works for passing around pointers until you reach the point where you need to access the actual library functions. Then you need the actual library header (to make sure the information is right), and if your structure tag is wrong, all hell breaks loose.  So, if you're going to play this game, make sure you get the structure tag correct.

Note that C11 allows a typedef to be repeated as long as it is the same each time, whereas earlier versions of C did not allow that.  This can be a considerable help.

### Working example

This is close to a minimal example that shows how it might be done.  It assumes C11 where the repeated `typedef` is legitimate.  It won't work for C99 or C89/C90 because the `typedef` for `FOO` is repeated when `projfunc.c` is compiled.  (There are various ways you can adapt it so that it will work in C99 or earlier, but they're messier, using `#ifdef` or similar around the `project.h` typedef — since the presumption is that you can't alter `library.h`; if you can, it is part of your project after all.)

The `project.h` header is used primarily by the general code that belongs to the project that uses the library defining `FOO` — which is represented by `projmain.c` in this example.  It can be used on its own, or with `library.h`, which is illustrated by `projfunc.c` which is the project code that actually interfaces to the library and makes calls to the library.  The file `library.c` only uses `library.h`.

You can play with alternative declarations of `FOO` in `project.h` to see what goes wrong where.  For example, `typedef struct BAR FOO;` will fail; so will `typedef struct FOO *FOO;`.

#### project.h

```
#ifndef PROJECT_H_INCLUDED
#define PROJECT_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct FOO FOO;

typedef struct Project
{
    FOO    *foop;
    char   *name;
    int     max;
    double  ratio;
} Project;

extern int proj_function(Project *pj);

#endif /* PROJECT_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### library.h

```
#ifndef LIBRARY_H_INCLUDED
#define LIBRARY_H_INCLUDED

typedef struct FOO
{
    int x;
    int y;
} FOO;

extern FOO *foo_open(const char *file);
extern int foo_close(FOO *foop);
extern int foo_read(FOO *foop, int *x, int *y);
extern int foo_write(FOO *foop, int x, int y);

#endif /* LIBRARY_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### projmain.c

```
#include "project.h"

int main(void)
{
    Project pj = { 0, 0, 0, 0.0 };

    if (proj_function(&pj) != 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

#### projfunc.c

```
#include "project.h"
#include "library.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int proj_function(Project *pj)
{
    int x, y;

    pj->foop = foo_open("classic-mode");
    if (foo_write(pj->foop, 1, 2) < 0)
    {
        foo_close(pj->foop);
        return -1;
    }
    if (foo_read(pj->foop, &x, &y) < 0)
    {
        foo_close(pj->foop);
        return -1;
    }
    printf("x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

#### library.c

```
#include "library.h"
#include <assert.h>

static FOO foo = { 0, 0 };

FOO *foo_open(const char *file)
{
    assert(file != 0);
    return &foo;
}

int foo_close(FOO *foop)
{
    assert(foop == &foo);
    foo.x = foo.y = 0;
    return 0;
}

int foo_read(FOO *foop, int *x, int *y)
{
    assert(foop == &foo);
    *x = foop->x + 1;
    *y = foo.y + 1;
    return 0;
}

int foo_write(FOO *foop, int x, int y)
{
    assert(foop == &foo);
    foo.x = x + 1;
    foop->y = y + 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: he could also simply use `struct FOO;` if he cares about the declaration rather than the `typedef`

Comment: @MooingDuck: yes, he could use `struct FOO *fp;` and as long as `struct FOO *` doesn't first appear in a function prototype, all will be well.  But the key point is knowing the correct structure tag to use.  (There's a good deal of 'it will work in practice', right up to the point that you get to code that needs to use the actual library.)

Answer (score 1):

The library should define FOO for you, either opaquely or transparently, as it's own source refers to FOO.

`#include <library.h>` should get you the prototypes to the functions the library provides, and also the types needed to interact with them.

If you create your own FOO type, you'll almost certainly get a compile error indicating multiple definition of 'FOO' when you include the function prototypes from the library.