# Private struct with property that must be public in .h file in C

Tags: c, struct, header

I'm working on a library for a user to use and manage with the function prototypes I provide within my header file. Now I have a working hashtable setup in manager.c but I'm at a loss at how to tackle this. I basically want to keep the hashtable "under the hood" from the user by providing them with

```
typedef struct Manager {
    int size;
    HashList **table;
} Manager;
```

so they can create this Manager object and use my provided functions to manipulate its contents. However, HashList is declared in my manager.c as

```
typedef struct HashList {
    /*
     * data stored here
     */
    struct HashList *next;
} HashList;
```

Now obviously this will not compile as HashList must be in my header file since struct Manager uses HashList. But I do not want HashList to be in the header file as the user shouldn't explicitly have access to this as my functions manipulate the data stored at each hash.

Any advice?

Answer (score 4):

1. If the user writes: `Manager *m = ...;`, is it expected that they'll ever write `m->xyz`?  If not, then you don't need to expose the internals to the end user at all — it is sufficient to provide them with:

   ```
   typedef struct Manager Manager;
   ```
2. If they must dereference the `Manager` type, it suffices to define:

   ```
   typedef struct HashList HashList;
   ```

   in the public header.  They don't need to access the insides of that.  (Well, if you've any pretensions to providing a concealed service, they have no need for that.)

Between the two options, option 1 is preferable.  You provide functions that create and destroy the `Manager` type, and that allow the user to get or set the size of the structure.  With the `FILE *` type, you don't write code that pokes inside the structure; you just use it via the interface functions you define.  You should enforce the same discipline on the users of your code.

Note that if you allow the user to poke at the `size` element in the `Manager` structure, you can never tell when they changed it, so you've no idea whether your structure has been corrupted.  If you have functional access to it (a `get` and a `set` function), you control what happens when the size changes.

Comment: Continuing off your example, I still would like the user to be aware of and access m->size.

Edit: Reading your edit is a good point. I don't exactly want the user to be able to change this size variable but still read if necessary. So I should just implement a get function for it.

Comment: @Kersh: think again!  You do **not** want them to do that.  Really, you don't.  If they can, they will set `size` to 0, -1, or 1 million.  And you won't know what the value was the last time your code got to look at it.  Anyway, I covered that possibility in option 2.  If you really, really *must* let them at the size, despite all the problems it is going to give you in terms of reliability, then you can do so using option 2.  See also [Am I correct to assume one cannot forward declare a library's opaque pointer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912385/27912450#27912450)

Comment: Thank you for that link, rather informative. I have some editing to do to my header file.

Comment: This is a very good answer of course coming from you, but wasn't there a duplicate? I don't think it's the first time someone asks this, if it is, then it's so sad. I did answer anyway because I believe this is a very good thing to learn.

Comment: @iharob: there's at least a partial duplicate referenced in my comment.  Since I wrote that answer this year, I would be surprised to find it was the original question on this topic.  That is, if you could find them, there are probably other, earlier questions that cover the same topic that also have the C tag.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your struct opaque. Keep the implementation details in the library `.c` files or a private header file and only provide a `typedef` only.

Example:

**library.c**

```
struct SomeStruct
{
    int value;
};

struct SomeStruct *some_struct_alloc()
{
    return malloc(sizeof(SomeStruct)));
}

void some_struct_set_value(struct SomeStruct *someStruct, int value)
{
    if (someStruct != NULL)
        someStruct->value = value;
}

int some_struct_value(struct SomeStruct *someStruct)
{
    if (someStruct != NULL)
        return someStruct->value;
    return SOME_INVALID_VALUE_PERHAPS;
}
```

**library.h**

```
typedef struct SomeStruct SomeStruct;

SomeStruct *some_struct_alloc();
void some_struct_set_value(SomeStruct *someStruct, int value);
int some_struct_value(SomeStruct *someStruct);
```

**program.c**

```
#include <library.h>

int main()
{
    SomeStruct *someStruct;

    someStruct = some_struct_alloc();
    if (someStruct == NULL)
        return -1;
    some_struct_set_value(someStruct, 3);
    printf("%s\n", some_struct_value(someStruct));

    free(someStruct);
    return 0;
}
```

If the user tries to dereference the `someStruct` in `main()` then the compiler would halt with an error similar to `dereferencing pointer of incomplete type`.

In my opinion, this is a very good way to protect your library's data structure from being misused.

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth example. I'm noticing minor changes I should be making to my current library.