# C struct definition problem with correct headers

Tags: c, header-files

Forgive my verbosity.

This is how i like headers to be made for declaring user functions in a module.

```
struct Object;
void function( struct Object * , ... );
```

This is just so that the user of a module doesn't have a cluttered header file with all the stuff being used in the struct.

With the .c file having the struct definition. And let us have structs inside this main struct.

```
struct Object {
    int item;
    struct Component component;
};
```

Let us want to use this module object in a struct defined by the user. Say:

```
#include "module.h" /*declarations*/
...
struct UserItem {
    int something;
    ...
    struct Object object;
} userThing;
```

Here comes my problem with C preprocessing.

This causes a problem. During compilation, the size of struct Object is not yet defined, so struct UserItem cannot be defined in size, failed compilation with `error: field 'object' has incomplete type`

Now what is the remedy?? Obviously one could use struct pointers but that adds annoying steps for struct initialisation, using dynamic memory allocation. What about having a separate header for struct definitions? Ok but this means that struct symbol names are now cluttered with these names like struct Component. Also a user would have to include this header file as well as the main module header file. This just isn't a nice solution in my eyes. Maybe even do something like `struct Object { uint8_t component_mem[SIZE]; };`

My only thoughts is to have a step in compilation where the struct definitions are pre-processed globally, such that all sizes are found. I believe this must be done already at the linking stage because of dereferencing struct pointers?

Let me know if I have made a mistake or there already exists a nice solution.

Similar stackoverflow page(s): [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29528746/c-struct-definition-in-header-files)

Comment: *"I believe this must be done already at the linking stage"* No, the linker knows nothing about struct definitions.

Comment: If the user code needs instances of the `Object` struct, and not just pointers to the `Object` struct, then good practice is to put the full definition in the header file.

Comment: @user3386109 I recognise this as the standard way to do it, but it conflicts with an idea of a clean and concise header file, free of any unnecessary definitions the user does not need to know about. I sometimes write structs within structs just for better readability, but this just means a more cluttered header file. I suppose my idea is impossible with the current state of compiling.

Comment: Yes, it is -- for the exact reasons you state in your question. That's just C. The only alternative are ugly kludges, or you basically reinvent the wheel attempting to write the foundation abstractions for an OOP language. Neither are a good use of your time. (other than for education sake) An interesting read on the approach is Chap 2 & 3 of [Object-Oriented Programming With ANSI-C](https://www.cs.rit.edu/~ats/books/ooc.pdf)  A close alternative, but program specific - every time... Another example  is the `png` struct in [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html)

Comment: Writing clean and concise header files is not a goal in C. Header files are filled with clutter: macro definitions, function prototypes, extern variable declarations, `struct` and `union` definitions.  Just take a look at the C library headers like stdio.h, stdlib.h, math.h, etc. They contain the clutter, so that the user code can be clean and concise.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin After a quick skim on those paragraphs, it is all about dynamic allocation. Hence the "annoying steps for struct initialisation" . Static allocation of structs whilst hiding definition of inner structs from the user is what I want from C. I appreciate your input nonetheless. Seems like a good read.

Comment: @user3386109 Not a goal in C? If i may claim innocence and ask why not? I would love a clean and concise header file. Seems a good way to outline functionality. Are there innate, unsurmountable problems with "a step in compilation where the struct definitions are pre-processed globally, such that all sizes are found"?

Comment: The insurmountable problem is that the compiler doesn't know the size of an incomplete type. That is intrinsic in the design of the C language. So your choices are: 1) accept that and get on with your life, 2) try to kludge around it, or 3) invent your own language.

Comment: @jinTgreater - If you go all the way back, the original goal of C was to allow Ken Thompson to implement UNIX in a higher level language. At the time, there was no need to hide implementation details, as he had written all of it himself! Later, one of their collegues chose option 3) and designed a language where the structs can have `private` and `public` parts.

Comment: @BoP Can we get a comeback of C with Classes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Information hiding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_hiding) is a noble goal, yet sometimes a pain.

C just does not support OP's goal, knowing the internals of `struct UserItem` by public files, but not use them.

The best I have seen is a **warning**.
Move the complete definition to the .h file

```
// Object.h
/*
I know you may be tempted to access these struct members, but **DO NOT USE THEM**.  
They are only here for sizing purposes and zero initialization.
Only Object support function should access members.
*/

struct Component {
    int SecretDecoderRing;
    double magic_number;
    char psword[42];
};

struct Object {
    int item;
    struct Component component;
};

void Object_function1( struct Object * , ... );
void Object_function2( struct Object * , ... );
```

`struct Component` definition, `struct Object` definition and the warning could instead exists in a separate Object_xxx.h file included by Object.h for a modest level of *hiding*.  Yet including Object.h still eventually exposes those `struct` details.

Comment: See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77427915/c-struct-definition-problem-with-correct-headers#comment136501348_77427915)

Comment: @jinTgreater `struct Object; void function( struct Object * , ... );` doesn't need the size of `struct Object`. Yet if you want to allow `struct UserItem { int something; ... struct Object object; } userThing;` instead of `struct UserItem { int something; ... struct *Object object; } userThing;`, note the *, then you are proceeding along a  design that needs `struct Object` complete definition - & the only way to hide the data is with a cooperative user who abides by the warning.

Comment: @jinTgreater I have tried tricks with `unions`, fixed sized buffers, `static_asserts`, etc. only to return to: trust the user, at least a little.

Comment: @jinTgreater If you do not want to trust the user, only allow `struct UserItem { int something; ... struct *Object object; } userThing;` with the `*`.